# Train models over a list by combining different elements of the list, return the combinations that gives the best score

Tags: python

I am trying to train several models over a dataset by using different combinations of the features list.
So far, I have this:

```
features = ['ca','thal','slope','oldpeak','chol','fbs','thalach','exang']
for i in range(1, len(features) + 1):  # iterate and select next features
    Sbest = [] # Sbest will contain the list of elements which give the best score
    input_f = features[:i]
    y = data['target']
    X = data[input_f] 
    model_= KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=100)
    model_.fit(X)
    precision,recall,fscore,support=score(y,model_.labels_,average='macro')
    Sbest.append(input_f)
    print(input_f,': {:.2f}'.format(fscore))
```

which gives the following output:

```
['ca'] : 0.62
['ca', 'thal'] : 0.62
['ca', 'thal', 'slope'] : 0.62
['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak'] : 0.71
['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak', 'chol'] : 0.42
['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak', 'chol', 'fbs'] : 0.42
['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak', 'chol', 'fbs', 'thalach'] : 0.56
['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak', 'chol', 'fbs', 'thalach', 'exang'] : 0.56
```

What I would like is to output the list of features that gives the best result, as we can see here, it's the one with the `fscore` of 0.71. So, instead of having all the outputs,
I want instead this output:

```
['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak'] : 0.71
```

And if it happened that I had different lists that output the same score, the output would be the one with less elements. What is missing from my code?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all the lists in the output because you are using `print(input_f,': {:.2f}'.format(fscore))` in the for loop.

You can append the tuple of list and its score to the Sbest list and then sort it based on the criteria you want.

Like so: (I modified the input list to have two lists of different length with same score)

```
a = [
(['ca'] , 0.62),
(['ca', 'thal'] , 0.62),
(['ca', 'thal', 'slope'] , 0.62),
(['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak'] , 0.71),
(['ca', 'thal', 'slope'] , 0.71),
(['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak', 'chol'] , 0.42),
(['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak', 'chol', 'fbs'] , 0.42),
(['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak', 'chol', 'fbs', 'thalach'] , 0.56),
(['ca', 'thal', 'slope', 'oldpeak', 'chol', 'fbs', 'thalach', 'exang'] , 0.56)
]

a.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: (x[1], -1*len(x[0])))
print(a[0])
```

which gives

```
(['ca', 'thal', 'slope'], 0.71)
```

So in your program, you can:

1. remove the print line from inside the loop.
2. Add input and score to SList by doing `Sbest.append((input, fscore))`
3. Once the loop is finished, sort and print the first item from Sbest `Sbest.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: (x[1], -1*len(x[0])))` and `print(Sbest[0])`

Comment: This returned the last score instead of the best one.

Comment: Keep the declartion of Sbest outside the loop otherwise you lose information of previous iterations. Thats why you saw only last score.

Comment: I figured it out but it returned a list of list

Comment: There is no return statement there. Sbest is a list of tuples. Sbest--> [([], float), ([], float),([], float)]

Comment: It's not like that, it's more like : Sbest --> [ [ 's'], float ] on every line and there is no comma between them.

Comment: How are you appending it in the first place. Can you paste that here?